# Working with numpy to operate with pure python lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have several portions of code in pure python like:

```
[final_ids.append(list_item[0]) for list_item in newNodesCoord]
for line in nodes:
    if line[0] not in final_ids:
        newNodesCoord.append([line[0], 0., 0., 0.])

for i,row in enumerate(deformedCoord):
    x,y,z,nx,ny=row 
    for j, line in enumerate(nodesL):
        nodeID,x2,y2,z2=line
        if x==x2 and y==y2 and z==z2:
           newNodesCoord.append([nodeID, nx, ny, 0.])
```

However as the size of the lists grow the performance of the code deteorates. Is there a faster way to do this using numpy?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NumPy arrays are not the best data structure for this.
NumPy arrays shine (performance-wise) when you can call a NumPy function on a nice big array. They don't do particularly well when you need to iterate through the array item-by-item or row-by-row, which is what you seem to be doing in your code.

---

Here are some other suggestions:

The line

```
line[0] not in final_ids:
```

can be sped up by making `final_ids` a `set` rather than a `list`.
[Testing membership in a set is `O(1)`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), while testing membership in a list is `O(n)`.

---

And similarly, make `nodesL` a `dict` mapping `(x,y,z)` to `nodeID` values. Then you could use:

```
for x, y, z, nx, ny in deformedCoord:
    if (x,y,z) in nodesL:
        nodeID = nodesL[x,y,z]
        newNodesCoord.append([nodeID, nx, ny, 0.])
```

If for each `(x,y,z)` there's more than one `nodeID` add:

```
for nid in nodeID:
    newNodesCoord.append([nid, nx, ny, 0.])
```

or

```
newNodesCoord.extend([[nid, nx, ny, 0.] for nid in nodeID])
```

Your double `for-loop` has time complexity `O(n*m)` where `n = len(deformedCoord)` and `m = len(nodesL)`. If you make `nodesL` a `dict`, then  `if (x,y,z) in nodesL` is `O(1)`, so the loop above runs in `O(n)` time.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm not convinced that iterating item by item is actually slower for a numpy array than for a list (although it could be, I've never timed it), but additionally, numpy arrays aren't very good if you need to dynamically add elements (i.e. changing the size).

Comment: It isn't the iteration per-se that makes it slow, its the Python code that you use inside the loop (e.g operating on each value item-by-item) which makes it slow. There is no leveraging of NumPy's fast underlying C/Fortran functions when one codes like that. That's what makes the item-by-item / row-by-row code slow. At least in my experience, every time I've timed it, NumPy arrays used like that is slower than plain Python code.

Comment: @jpcgandre: I've altered your edit since `for nid in nodeID` is preferred over `for i in xrange(0, len(nodeID))` in Python whenever possible. It's more readable, and shorter to write, and avoids the slower `nodeID[i]` in favor of `nid`.